# I send any email with website that also show me on my email's sent box

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

Hello I have 1 question that i want to integrate my outlook with my django website that means if i send any email with website that also show me on my email's sent box. Can anyone help me to do this.

Comment: Which email provider are you using? Gmail, Outlook.com ?

Comment: If you google `django email "sent folder"` you will find a lot of information about it.

Comment: i am using outlook